# Sort logs when test run parallel using Specflow.MsTest

Tags: logging, log4net, specflow, log4net-filter

I am using [*Specflow.MsTest*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.MsTest) and executing acceptance tests in parallel. I'm using [*log4net*](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for logging.

When we run tests in parallel, the order of the log entries get scrambled up in the log file. I want to sort the log file based on scenario. How can I achieve that?

I want the logs to be displayed in the order and grouping I show below:

---

### Log File

```
Scenario : A

Login successful

Save

scenario ends

***************
Scenario : B

Login successful

Save

scenario ends
***************
```